# How did Piccolo meet his bird partner?

Tags: dragon-ball

After Goku attended his second World Martial Arts Tournament, Krillin been killed.

When Piccolo then appears on screen, he has a partner (a bird) with him on the ship. 
How did Piccolo meet him?

Comment: I do not know any information about it. Thinking about your question I came to a thesis: Piccolo was the evil family, then chances are met by the simple fact of being evil. Piccolo wanted to dominate the world and turns it into a hell, it is natural that demons to join him. For me this is the best explanation of how the two met.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Piano](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Piano) was the first son of King Piccolo. A Mutated Namek Piccolo created by spitting an egg.